# Add class to element with Handlebars based on property

Tags: handlebars.js

I loop with a handlebars #each through objets with a given boolean property like:

```
elements: [
  {
    text: "a"
    active: true
  },
  {
    text: "b"
    active: false
  }
]
```

What is the simplest way to add a class to an html element based on that property? Something like this:

```
{{#each elements}}
  <article class={{if active 'active-class'}}>
  ...
{{/each}}
```

I'm using handlebars 4.0.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to start by opening up a [helper block](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html):

```
{{#if}}
```

Then, you add the argument you're checking against (in this case a boolean):

```
{{#if active}}
```

Then, you close it like this:

```
{{#if active}}{{/if}}
```

Then, the content you want to render if the condition is met goes in-between the curly braces:

```
{{#if active}}text{{/if}}>
```

---

So, your HTML would look something like:

```
{{#each elements}}
    <article {{#if active}}class="active"{{/if}}>
    ...
{{/each}}
```

Or, if you also want a static class within that element you could do:

```
{{#each elements}}
    <article class="example {{#if active}}active{{/if}}">
    ...
{{/each}}
```